# (Angular 5/Typescript) @Input() not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components parent & child, and i want to pass the category defined in parent to be used in child. But getting error undefined.

Parent Component:

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  category: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.category = "Human";
  }
```

And the Child component is:

```
export class MenuListComponent implements OnInit{
 @Input() category: string;
 // category = 'Man';
 constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.category);
}
```

Parent component template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <app-menu-list></app-menu-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output is undefined.

Comment: Can you add template code as well please so we can see how you're passing the input?

Comment: @user184994 Added the template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually need to pass your variable to the child:

```
<app-menu-list [category]="category"></app-menu-list>
```